# gcc unable to find cpp files of different projects in a solution

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I built a solution in Visual Studio that contains three projects.
I am trying to compile the same on gcc using mingw.

Command: g++ -std=c++11  Cpp11-BlockingQueue.cpp uniTest_MyBQ.cpp gtest_main.cpp gtest-all.cpp -o  uniTest_MyBQ.exe

Error: No such file or directory for every cpp file
I gave path to solution folder and used the following command

**Following are the directories under BlockingQueue**

```
C:\Users\Apuroopa\Desktop\Blocking_Q\Nevelex_FinalSolution\BlockingQueue\BlockingQueue>dir
 Volume in drive C is Windows8_OS
 Volume Serial Number is FE19-7E65

 Directory of C:\Users\Apuroopa\Desktop\Blocking_Q\Nevelex_FinalSolution\BlockingQueue\BlockingQueue

07/18/2016  10:50 AM    <DIR>          .
07/18/2016  10:50 AM    <DIR>          ..
07/18/2016  09:50 AM    <DIR>          BlockingQueue
07/18/2016  10:08 AM        12,517,376 BlockingQueue.sdf
07/18/2016  09:50 AM             1,932 BlockingQueue.sln
07/18/2016  10:51 AM    <DIR>          Debug
07/18/2016  10:07 AM    <DIR>          googleTest
07/18/2016  09:50 AM    <DIR>          unitTest_MyBQ
               2 File(s)     12,519,308 bytes
               6 Dir(s)  255,527,034,880 bytes free
```

Comment: Show your actual command and actual error messages. Ditch the picture, it conveys no information.

Comment: included terminal image in the post

Comment: Please do not post images of text, they are good to stare at but you cannot actually work with one. Please use your text copy/paste functionality to post actual text.

Comment: Do you think you have these files in the current directory? How would you check that?

Comment: I have included the same command in text too. All the three projects Blocking Queue, googleTest and unitTest_MyBQ are in the solution directory BlockingQueue.
unitTest_MyBQ is set ass starting project

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning earlier.
The googleTest project in this solution is included as a static library

Comment: I have no idea what a "project" or "solution" would be in the context of gcc. There are files that sit in folders. Your current folder is **here I would copy and paste text from your post, but I cannot, because it's an image**. Is there a file named Cpp11-BlockingQueue.cpp in that folder? How would you verify that? (Hint: type `dir` at the command prompt).

Comment: I have included the dir command results in the post.  CppBlockingQueue.cpp is in BlockingQueue dir, gtest_main.cpp and gtest-all.cpp in googleTest directory and unitTest_MyBQ.cpp is in unitTest_MyBQ folder

Comment: gcc cannot find files that are "somewhere in there". It needs a [path](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)). If `unitTest_MyBQ.cpp` is in `unitTest_MyBQ` folder, then the path would be  `unitTest_MyBQ\unitTest_MyBQ.cpp`.

Comment: Nice to see Syracuse student here using Fawcett's library :p